# Manga about a reincarnated boy and beastman who died in the same bus crash

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I found this Manga a while ago and I want to read it again. The story started by a boy with black hair who gets academic help by the king. The noble's student hated him and even try to kill the boy by leaving him in a cliff with a monster.

The boy survived and asked permission from his teacher so he can go. After some time the noble family sent a beastman slave to kill the boy. But the boy managed to release the slave collar. After sometime the boy realized the slave was reincarnated too, and they died from the same bus crash.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[Seirei Gensouki: Spirit Chronicles](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/seirei-gensouki-spirit-chronicles)***...?

> Meet Rio: a callous orphaned boy living in the slums. At only 7-years-old, he realizes he's actually the reincarnation of Haruto Amakawa, a Japanese university student with a tragic past. While still reeling from this shocking epiphany, Rio also comes to learn that he possesses extremely potent magical abilities and uses his new powers to solve the kidnapping case of a little girl. His good deed is acknowledged, and he's rewarded by being enrolled into… a prestigious academy for noble children...?

At the age of seven, Rio -- a black-haired orphan boy living in the slums of a kingdom in another world -- regains memories of a previous life as Amakawa Haruto, a Japanese university student who died when the bus he was on was hit by a truck. An elementary schoolgirl named Endo Suzune was on the same bus and died as well. She secretly had a crush on Haruto, and took the bus rather than the train to be near him.

> [image: "Seirei Gensouki: Spirit Chronicles," chapter 13, page 4.]

In chapter 2, Rio encounters a search party looking for a kidnapped girl. He subsequently locates the girl, and it turns out that she's actually the second princess, Flora. The King rewards Rio by enrolling him in the royal academy, but some of the other students there, including a boy named Alfons, resent his presence, believing that an orphan from the slums has no right to be there.

In chapter 10, during a field exercise, the students are attacked by some goblins and an orc, and in the confusion, Alfons bumps into Flora, knocking her off a cliff edge. Rio saves her but ends up falling from the cliff himself, and uses his magic to land safely. He heads back to the other students, who've managed to deal with the orc and the goblins, but just as he's nearing them, he overhears Alfons blaming him for Flora's fall. The group is then attacked by a minotaur, which Rio defeats.

In chapter 15, Rio is attacked by a beastgirl assassin named Latifa, while he's alone in the woods. After knocking her out, he sees that she's wearing a slave neckring that subjects her to pain if she doesn't follow her master's orders. He frees her from the neckring, and out of gratitude, she becomes his travelling companion. Neither of them recognise one another yet, but Latifa is the reincarnation of Endo Suzune, the girl who died on the bus with Amakawa Haruto.

> [image: "Seirei Gensouki: Spirit Chronicles," chapter 16, page 14.]